# How do I block my site from redirecting to other sites

Tags: php, javascript, .htaccess

The problem is that my site uses a script on another site to deliver a link to a user. But if the user types something in incorrectly the script just redirects to the other site and I don't want users knowing that my site uses other services.

Is there a way to use .htaccess to block the redirection to the other site? All I need to block is one page on the other site called "error.html" and I don't want to block the entire site either.

Also I cannot show the code for security reasons.

Comment: Sounds like you are in a mess.  You need to, at a minimum, show *some* code, because "my site uses a script on another site to deliver a link to a user" could mean a lot of things.

Comment: Can this external JavaScript be copied to your sever and loaded from there?

Comment: “I don't want users knowing that my site uses other services.” You can't prevent that. I can always look at my HTTP traffic and see that your site loads scripts from external sites.

Answer (score 5):

If you allow third-party JavaScript on your site, these scripts can do anything with your client side behavior, including but not limited to redirection.  Plus, your .htaccess has nothing to do with JavaScript since it's server-side and JavaScript is client side.  Meaning your .htaccess can't prevent a browser from performing a JavaScript redirection.

And what's this "Also I cannot show the code for security reasons."? You mean a security reason bigger than you allowing third-party JavaScript on your site?

Answer (score 4):

Can you validate that user input is acceptable to the other site before redirecting there? It seems like blocking a page is less likely to be successful. If you know what works and what doesn't, then don't allow anything that won't work to be sent to the other site.